# How to click on a specific position of a web element in selenium?

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am working on video player automation. I am having difficulties in clicking at the end of the video player progress bar.
Consider an example of youtube video.
with the help of xpath i was able to find out the element of video progress bar. Now i wanted to click at the end of the video.

i tried using ***moveToElement(ele, xOffset, yOffset)***. But i can not have static offset here as the video player size depends on the browser window size.  I tried to get the size of web element and use it as xoffset but that did not seem to be working. ***moveToElement(ele, ele.getRect().getWidth()-10, yOffset)***.  Any suggestions here on how to achieve this?

Comment: Can you post the relevant HTML code?

Comment: How did you locate the video progress bar in youtube. Video is inside a html5 video tag.

Comment: I just wrote an answer for a very similar question you might be interested in... http://stackoverflow.com/a/40557587/2386774.

Comment: Considering from the example video [https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=arj7oStGLkU], The HTML code looks like below `<div class="ytp-progress-bar-container" style="height: 5px;">
<div class="ytp-progress-bar" tabindex="0" role="slider" aria-label="Seek slider" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="843" aria-valuenow="12" aria-valuetext="0:12 of 14:03">
<div class="ytp-progress-bar-padding"></div>
<div class="ytp-progress-list">` @Grasshopper we can get hold of element with the help of xpath example: `//div[@class='ytp-progress-list']`

Comment: @JeffC I had tried something similar, trying to get the width and height of my element and setting the X and Y offset. Theoretically speaking this should have worked but i did not see the element getting clicked!

Comment: @Manoj You are correct. Guess I did not look hard enough first time. Have you tried using javascript executor to change the value of 'aria-valuenow' of the div ytp-progress-bar.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Try this code. I tried on Chrome 54 with webdriver 2.53 on windows 8. Do not touch the mouse during test or even better move the cursor out of screen range when test starts.

```
   WebElement elem = driver.findElement(By.className("ytp-progress-bar"));

    int width = elem.getSize().getWidth();

    Actions act = new Actions(driver);
    act.moveToElement(elem).moveByOffset((width/2)-2, 0).click().perform();
```

You can figure out the offset from the many attributes in the div 'ytp-progress-bar'. You do not need to find width etc.

You have to move to the progress bar initially because it disappears after 2-3 secs due to inactivity on the video screen.

Comment: The above code works(with X-offset -50 it clicks at time 5:40). But, the position it clicks when the size of the video differs(Theater mode, full screen mode etc) is different. I am trying to figure a way out to click at the end of the video irrespective of the screen size.

Comment: Use the width of the progress bar and minus small size. Try the edited code. Works in all 3 sizes.

Comment: Works like a charm. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

To get the exact location to click on a page, there is a free firefox add-on that can help you achieve this accuracy. It is called 'MeasureIt'. With this, you can measure the exact vertical and horizontal distances you want to click

Comment: But if the resolution/ screen size differs then the x-y coordinates location would change. We can get the exact location of the element dynamically `element.getLocation()` , setting coordinates from the output of this with certain offset does not seem to be working!

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes Selenium is not enough and you need to work with Javascript and JQuery. I am not a Java developer but the code in C# would look like:

```
IJavaScriptExecutor js = (IJavaScriptExecutor)driver;
js.ExecuteScript("Your Script");
```

There will be more help with JQuery. I hope I was able to help you.

Comment: I tried setting up the attribute values through JS `js.executeScript("arguments[0].setAttribute(arguments[1], arguments[2]);", 
                element, attName, attValue);` but found no luck as there were too many attribute changes in the DOM and it is difficult to track them all.

Answer (score 0):

```
public void clickCenterElement(WebElement element){
        Actions ac = new Actions(driver);
        ac.moveToElement(element,0,0).click().build().perform();
    }
```

this works to me